# Error message on my New Blog Post page which I cannot work out

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I am in the process of incorporating a Blog Posts section in my website.

However I am receiving an error message on the New Post page which I am unsure of the cause of.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Error Message]

I have received the above two Warning Error messages above.

I have also covered parts of the directory because they show names.

This is what the code looks like at the line specified.

```
<?php

include "cms/posts.php";

?>
```

Line 155 is the middle line of code.

If there is any more information which is required please let me know.

Thanks!

Reply to comment 1: Hi, I'm not sure why it is trying to open that file as I've never seen or heard of the file "usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php".

Comment: Have you checked that included files exist in these directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code and make sure the file exists:

```
<?php

include __DIR__ . "/cms/posts.php"; // PHP >= 5.3

include dirname(__FILE__) . "/cms/posts.php";  // PHP < 5.3

?>
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "(PHP >= 5.3):"? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I tried adding that code:

    <?php

    include __DIR__ . "/cms/posts.php";
    //include "cms/posts.php";

    ?>


Now it returns this error.


Warning: include(/home/s1307798/public_html/jamesfrewin/login/cms/cms/posts.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/s1307798/public_html/jamesfrewin/login/cms/index.php on line 154

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/s1307798/public_html/jamesfrewin/login/cms/cms/posts.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/s1307798/public_html/jamesfrewin/login/cms/index.php on line 154

Comment: Make sure you do not forget the underscores: **__DIR__** or try to drop the "cms" folder after include

Comment: Same problem sadly, even with the underscores :-/

Comment: And have you tried this: `include __DIR__ . "/posts.php"` ?

Comment: No problem, have a nice coding day!